# Search and display on same page in mvc2 asp net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

have a simple search form with a textbox. And upon submitting the form I send the contents of the textbox to a stored procedure which returns to me the results. I want the results to be displayed on the same page the form was, except just below it.

Right now I'm doing the following but it's not working out exactly the way I want:

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: It's two different actions, with two different models.  Why would you not put them on separate pages, or loaded it through an AJAX call.

Comment: @Brandon See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571715/search-results-to-be-displayed-on-the-same-page-mvc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ajax` to solve the problem.

```
<div>
`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "results",
        HttpMethod = "GET",
    }))
    {
        @Html.TextBox()
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }`
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

sathishkumar,

You don't tag the question as being an ajax related solution or not. I'm going to present a simple ajax approach which may or may not be suitable.

in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm)
{
    // you don't add code re your stored proc, so here is a repo based approach
    var searchItems = _repository.Find(x => x.searchfield.Contains(searchTerm));
    return PartialView("SearchPartial", searchItems);
}
```

main view (index.aspx or whatever) (below where your main content is defined, add):

```
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

in another part of the page (semi psuedo-code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getSearchResults() {
         // #yoursearchbox is a textbox on the index.aspx aview
         var tdata = { searchTerm: $('#yoursearchbox').val()}; 
         // or your data in the format that will be used ??
         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           data: tdata,
           url : '<%= Url.Action("Search", "Home") %>',
           success: function (result) { success(result); }  
        });
      }); 

    function success(result){
        $("#searchResults").html(result);
    }
</script>
```

You'd then add a partial view SearchPartial.ascx that contained your model for the search results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571715/search-results-to-be-displayed-on-the-same-page-mvc2